# Vue component's description for vue-docgen-api in script setup

Tags: vue.js, storybook, nuxtjs3, documentation-generation

The [vue-docgen-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-docgen-api/v/4.50.0) shows an example of component description in the "old" options style:

```js
<script>
import { text } from './utils'

/**
 * This is an example of creating a reusable grid component and using it with external data.
 * @version 1.0.5
 * @author [Rafael](https://github.com/rafaesc92)
 * @since Version 1.0.1
 */
export default {
  name: 'grid',
  props: {
     ...
```

Is there a way to add description to the component in Nuxt3 in script setup?

Comment: sadly, not yet :/